# How to use backends in google app engine without wasting cpu resources?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, backend

While processing data in datastore using backends, app engine is using my cpu resources completely. 
How do i process my data without wasting CPU resources?

Can i have the entire app on a backend without wasting cpu resources?

am i missing something..
if the question is too vague, ask me to clarify.. thanks

Comment: why do you feel it's wasted? isn't it possible that it's using all the resources it can get purposefully?

Comment: @Nicolas, the class configuration i'm using is 256MB, 1.GHz, i think the task i'm doing can be done using that configuration well with in an hour with one instance, but the cpu resources are maxing out with backend resources nearly 80 percent available.

Comment: @nicolas, can i have the entire app run on a backend instance without using cpu resources. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general advice for optimizing CPU usage is to minimize RPCs, understand how to use the datastore efficiently and use appstats to find your bottlenecks. For specific optimization advice, we would need to see some code.

While backends can be configured to handle public requests, they aren't intended to replace normal instances. Backends are designed for resource-intensive offline processing. Normal instances are created and destroyed automatically in response to request volume; backends have to be configured and instantiated explicitly by an administrator, thus they are not well-suited to handling traffic spikes.

They're also more expensive: keeping a backend instance online for 24 hours will cost you $3.84, whether the instance is handling requests or not.

Comment: well my main task is to pre process the data in the datastore before using it as an application, the backend wont be running all the time, i didnt know about appstats earlier, so i'll look into it thanks